# Removing Primary Key and Joining Rows in Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I'm trying to sort a DataTable to be able to get the best selling items by order in C#. The DataTable's fields are **orderId**, **productId**, **size**, and **amount** (amount = how much of it was bought). The current primary key in the table is comprised of **orderId**, **productId**, and **size**. I would like to get the best selling items by sorting the table in a way that would remove **orderId**, and have **productId** and **size** as the new primary key, and **amount** as the sum of all **amount**'s for orders with this **productId** and **size**.
What would be the best way to do this? I'm attaching my current table data for reference. [My table data for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CBGN.png).
If anything is unclear please let me know, this is my first time using Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication20
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("orderid", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("productid", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("size", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("amount", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 1, 38, 12 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 1, 41, 6 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 2, 36, 8 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 2, 38, 5 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 3, 46, 2 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, 3, 40, 7 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 8, 3, 40, 7 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 9, 2, 40, 9 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 12, 2, 37, 5 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 13, 2, 37, 4 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 14, 2, 38, 3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 15, 3, 41, 4 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 16, 2, 36, 7 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 16, 3, 41, 5 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 17, 2, 38, 4 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 18, 3, 40, 3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 19, 5, 38, 9 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 20, 2, 36, 2 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 21, 1, 40, 3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 22, 1, 38, 8 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 23, 1, 40, 9 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 24, 2, 37, 1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 25, 5, 39, 4 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2034, 3, 40, 3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2035, 2, 37, 6 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2035, 3, 40, 5 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2036, 2, 36, 2 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2037, 2, 37, 3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2037, 3, 41, 7 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2038, 1, 39, 3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2038, 5, 37, 4 });

            var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => new { productid = x.Field<int>("productid"), size = x.Field<int>("size") })
                .Select(x => new { productid = x.Key.productid, size = x.Key.size, count = x.Count(), total = x.Sum(y => y.Field<int>("amount")) })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.count)
                .ToList();
 
        }
    }
 
    
}
```